# How do we control the Clients in the Task set execution in Locust?

Tags: python, locust

1. Is there any way to get the current executed Client information
   inside the Task set class? We can get the Thread number in Jmeter.
   Like that can we get the Client number in Locust tool?
2. Suppose I'm executing the 20 requests with 5 clients. Can i say that each 
   client is executing 4 requests (20/5 = 4 request each)? What is the internal
   mechanism using here to execute those 20 requests by using 5
   clients?
3. This question is related to the data given in **Question: 2**, Is that execution is happened iteration-wise. Like 1st iteration, Client 1, 2, 3 ,4 and 5 are executing request 1, 2,3, 4 and 5 respectively. Next iteration, again Client 1, 2, 3 ,4 and 5 are executing requests 6,7,8,9 and 10 respectively. **How could we achieve this type of execution mechanism in Locust tool.** Is this possible?

   Please help me to clarify above questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think there's built-in support for it. You could set an id yourself in the `on_start` method
2. Each Locust will trigger a new task after the previous task was finished (taking into account the wait period). If your response time has a small variation, you can assume that the requests are equally distributed.
3. No, the Locusts are picking tasks one after the other, but are not waiting their turn. When a Locust is available, it will pick a task and execute it. I don't think there is support for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get the current executed Client information inside the Task set class?

There is not currently. The [data sent to the client does not include this](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/runners.py#L289-L301) when the orchestrator creates the client. This behavior has been requested a few times though.

> Suppose I'm executing the 20 requests with 5 clients. Can i say that each client is executing 4 requests (20/5 = 4 request each)? What is the internal mechanism using here to execute those 20 requests by using 5 clients?

This question has incorrect assumptions.

Each Locust has a [minimum and maximum weight time](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#locust.core.Locust.max_wait) which determines how much time is waited between tasks.

Each locust chooses tasks randomly, based on the task weighting and this interval. The controls for "executing 20 requests with 5 clients" mean that Locust will start 5 clients and once it has received the results for 20 requests, terminate.

It is possible, depending on how long your calls take that they will be evenly distributed. Or, most could be completed by one client.

> This question is related to the data given in Question: 2, Is that execution is happened iteration-wise. Like 1st iteration, Client 1, 2, 3 ,4 and 5 are executing request 1, 2,3, 4 and 5 respectively. Next iteration, again Client 1, 2, 3 ,4 and 5 are executing requests 6,7,8,9 and 10 respectively. How could we achieve this type of execution mechanism in Locust tool. Is this possible?

You can nest task sets together. But the concept of "iteration" doesn't really make sense within the Locust framework. Locust is designed to deal with randomly picking and creating tasks based on weightings.

If your goal is explicit iterations where you run a set of tasks and then move to the next iteration, to run different tasks, you will find that Locust doesn't really support this use case well.

You *could* [write your own client](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/testing-other-systems.html) to do this and manually fire the events as needed, however I'm not sure the overhead would be worth it if you fundamentally want to use Locust in a way it's not intended.